# Can I write my owm template in TextFormatter used in Logging Application Block in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, exception, enterprise-library

Can I write my owm template in TextFormatter used in Logging Application Block in C#?

Basically I want to write my exception log in atext file and in specific format where I want to include database information and software version.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309274.aspx) you can find more information about extending the Logging Application Block.

Answer (score 0):

You can make different listeners for text writing and database writing. You can then point the listeners to different text formatters you can change format of the data. However you have to organise the message you pass to it first. The default text formatter has allot of extra information you may or may not want.

Here is a example of a changed text formatter you can have as many listeners and formatters as required. This will change your text file without having to change the code.

Thanks
Alex

```
  <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    template="{message}{newline}"
    name="TextAuditFormater" />
```